# how to find an element based on two selectors?

Tags: javascript, jquery, find, contains, belongs-to

i have a doom tree like this:

```
ul #navigation
    li .active
    ul
        li.active_li
        li
        li
    /ul
    li
    ul
        li.active_li
        li
        li
    /ul
/ul
```

i would like to find the `li` with a class of `active_li` inside the `ul` belonging to the `li` that has a class of `active`. :)

as we can see there are 2 `li` with a class of `active_li`. i want only the first one

something like: `$('#navigation').find('li.active').find('li.active)li').doSomething();`

this selector doesn't seem to work

any ideas?

Comment: `jQuery` has the same concept of descendant/ancestor selectors as CSS .. this will work: $('#navigation li.active_li');  Could it be the parent vs. underscore?

Comment: @tandu: I think it's safe to say that any CSS selector will work as a jQuery selector.

Comment: @Blender it's not .. jQuery has no concept of some of the pseudo-class selectors of CSS, does not support media queries and the like (not that those would make sense), and does not support CSS 4 selectors (which are incomplete and unused).  CSS is certainly not compatible with jQuery selectors -- not that you said that.

Comment: @tandu: jQuery's selector engine will happily parse *most* CSS selectors. There are a few exceptions (mostly obscure pseudo-classes, but those logically don't belong in jQuery code): http://ejohn.org/blog/selectors-that-people-actually-use/

Comment: @Blender the link does not seem relevant to what we were talking about .. jQuery does not implement `:hover`, `:visited`, or `:active` -- I would not call those obscure and I wouldn't say that they logically don't belong in jQuery code -- if they didn't, why implement `:focus` as a selector?

Comment: @tandu: `:visited` is masked by the web browser so that scripts cannot use styling to determine what links a person visited. The other two pseudo-selectors are action-driven, so they should be replaced with the appropriate jQuery functions (`.hover()` and `.click()`).

Comment: @Blender jQuery is supposed to be a framework that abstracts some capabilities not immediately inherent to JavaScript and vendor-specific -- detecting link visitation is a possibility in some instances.  As for the other two elements being "action-driven," this is not necessarily true.  Especially in the case of `:active`, it is not analogous to `.click()` and you should disabuse yourself of that notion.  These were just a few examples.  My main point is that "I *don't* think it's safe to say that *any* CSS selector will work as a jQuery selector."  They even differ in semantic meaning..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this selector:

```
$('#navigation li.active ul li.active_li')
                         ^^
                          \_ You can get rid of this, as <li> elements
                             exist only within <ul> elements.
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
$('#navigation li.active li.active_li').each(function(){

});
```

and flag the function off after running the first one.

Or if you just want the first one selected:

```
 $('#navigation li.active li.active_li').first();
```